# Supremum of distance between two functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ be metric spaces and $C_b(X,Y)$ be the set of continuous bounded functions $f:X\to Y$. Then how does one prove that $\sup\limits_{x\in X}d_Y(f(x), g(x))<\infty$?

[Bounded means that $f(X)$, the image of $X$ under $f$, has finite diameter.]

Comment: How do you define *bounded*?

Comment: Bounded means that $f(X)$, the image of $X$ under $f$, has finite diameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists $M,N$ such that $d(f(x),f(y))<M$ and $d(g(x),g(y))<N$ for every $x\in X$. Let $x_0\in X$,

$d(f(x),g(x))\leq d(f(x),f(x_0))+d(f(x_0),g(x_0))+d(g(x_0),g(x))$

$\leq M+N+d(f(x_0),g(x_o))$.